# Como pasar una columnas JSON a columna SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una tabla donde una columna se guarda en formato JSON y quisiera que ese JSON que tiene dentro diferente sea dinamico,
Esta es la tabla que tengo:

```
CREATE TABLE [com].[HBDK008](
    [HROWID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HFECPRO] [date] NOT NULL
    [HDESTER] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    HJSON nvarchar(max)  
)
insert into storage.[com].[HBDK008] values('2022-09-30','CENTRO ORIENTE_IND','{"RSALCART":1500,"RNUMCLI":50,"REFEC30A0":24,"REFEC1A30":15,"RNUMUSA":100,"RNUMCORRES":12,"RNUMCOSATE":5}')
```

Lo que está dentro del JSON puede variar el nodo el nombre y quisiera que cuando haga select se coloque como columnas
he estado intentando con JSON_VALUE lo unico malo es que tengo que ponerlo en forma estricta pero como va ser dinamico me da un error.

He estado intentado así:

```
 SELECT  hfecpro,JSON_VALUE(hjson ,'$.RSALCART') AS RSALCART 
FROM  storage.[com].[HBDK008]
```

**quisiera que se muestre todo sin colocar estrictamente el nombre del campo**

Comment: Se me ocurre que tendrias que hacerlo con SQL Dinamico obtener los keys y luego pasarlos de manera dinamica, mi pregunta seria por que no poner los campos? seria muy complejo? por que en dado caso que no exista simplemente quedaria null

Comment: @EdgarVazquez Mil gracias por responder, lo que sucede es que van hacer varias variables y en el sp donde va estar va estar varias lineas de código, por fa ayudame :(

Comment: Pero esta en una tabla, ahi no pudiera venir mas de un registro? por que de ser asi, se complica todavia un poco mas si me dices que solo sera un item puedo ayudarte

Comment: No me queda muy claro lo que quieres lograr, en parte porque solo das un ejemplo con una línea de datos y luego dices que "puede variar". Si es así, sugiero que incluyas varias líneas de datos de ejemplo y amplíes para entender que tanto _puede variar_. Sugiero que incluyas un ejemplo, en texto, de lo que quieres obtener _con los datos de ejemplo_ que pusiste.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que requieres es enlistar los KEY y sus valores con un OUTER podrias resolverlo de una manera rapida, eso si por cada key te generará un nuevo item

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE(
    [HROWID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HFECPRO] [date] NOT NULL,
    [HDESTER] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    HJSON nvarchar(max)  
)
insert into @T values('2022-09-30','CENTRO ORIENTE_IND','{"RSALCART":1500,"RNUMCLI":50,"REFEC30A0":24,"REFEC1A30":15,"RNUMUSA":100,"RNUMCORRES":12,"RNUMCOSATE":5}')

SELECT *
FROM  @T C
OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT *
        FROM OPENJSON(c.HJSON, '$') AS j1
    )v
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/FwWBpvkE

```
Ahora si lo quieres uno por uno seria asi
DECLARE @T AS TABLE(
    [HROWID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HFECPRO] [date] NOT NULL,
    [HDESTER] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    HJSON nvarchar(max)  
)
insert into @T values('2022-09-30','CENTRO ORIENTE_IND','{"RSALCART":1500,"RNUMCLI":50,"REFEC30A0":24,"REFEC1A30":15,"RNUMUSA":100,"RNUMCORRES":12,"RNUMCOSATE":5}')

SELECT HROWID,HFECPRO,HDESTER,
 JSON_VALUE(c.HJSON,'$.RSALCART')  RSALCART,
 JSON_VALUE(c.HJSON,'$.RNUMCLI') AS  RNUMCLI,
 JSON_VALUE(c.HJSON,'$.REFEC1A30') AS  REFEC1A30,
 JSON_VALUE(c.HJSON,'$.RNUMCORRES') AS  RNUMCORRES,
 JSON_VALUE(c.HJSON,'$.RNUMCOSATE') AS  RNUMUSA
FROM  @T C
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/yGQklPLb

Como podras ver si no existe la columna no pasa nada simplemente lo deja null

Comment: No necesitas usar `SELECT * FROM` dentro del `APPLY`. Puedes referenciar directamente la función `OPENJSON`.